# php login script does not redirect secure page on server side (remote host)

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have simple login script which is working on my local host with no problem. However, when I upload to the remote host what I am getting is a white screen. After I submit the user name password it doesn't take me to the secure index page and if I type it manually I can access the page.

Here is the code I am using...

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("script/db.php");


// username and password sent from Form
$login_name= $_POST['login_name'];
$password= $_POST['password'];



$login_name = stripslashes($login_name);
$password= stripslashes($password);
$login_name= mysql_real_escape_string($login_name);
$password= mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query="SELECT id_user, iduserlevel FROM user WHERE login_name='$login_name' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$iduserlevel=$row['iduserlevel'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
session_register("login_name");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$login_name;
$_SESSION['iduserlevel']=$iduserlevel;
header("location: secure/index.php");
}
else
{
echo "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";

}
mysql_close(); 
?>
<a href="index.php" > Please Try Again</a>
```

**lock.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}

include("script/db.php");

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$query=mysql_query("select login_name, iduserlevel,y from user where login_name='$user_check' ");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

$login_session=$row['login_name'];
$iduserlevel_session=$row['iduserlevel'];
$iduserlevel_sessiony=$row['y'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("location: index.php");
}
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

**secure/index.php**

```
<?php include("../lock.php");?>

<?php

....

?>
```

Comment: please don't put this code into production use.  There's too much here that's wrong to even begin.... well, SQL Injection for 1.  you can't take $_POST data and put it into a query.  You might as well put a sign around your neck that says, "Please beat me up."

Comment: I hope you'll be sanitizing that input in your production copy? So that someone with the username `'; DELETE * FROM user` doesn't try to login

Comment: i just edited the code for mysql injection but still have the same problem

Comment: There may be an error occurring somewhere so make sure you turn on error reporting or set it on the top of that page temporarily. You can use: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

```
header("location: secure/index.php");
```

For something like:

```
header("location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/secure/index.php");
```

And filter $POST for sql injection

Comment: still same issue just white screen but after login if i type secure page its working

Comment: Check your php.ini and find the variable with the name "error_reporting" change to show everything like:                                               error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_USER_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're using an associative array for query. If you're going to do that, use

mysql_fetch_assoc() not array().

IE.

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);